# Is RxJS.Observable a monad?

Tags: javascript, haskell, rxjs, observable

Is Observable really a monad? Does it abide by Monad laws (https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws)? Doesn't seem to me like it does. But maybe my understanding is wrong and somebody can shed some light on the issue. My current reasoning is (I'm using **::** to denote "is of kind"):

*1) Left identity:*  **return a >>= f ≡ f a**

```
var func = x => Rx.Observable.of(10)

var a = Rx.Observable.of(1).flatMap(func) :: Observable
var b = func(1)                           :: ScalarObservable
```

HASKELL:

```
func = (\_ -> putStrLn "B")

do { putStrLn "hello"; return "A" } >>= func   :: IO ()

func "A"                                       :: IO ()
```

So left identity doesn't hold for Observable. Observable clearly isn't ScalarObservable. In Haskell, the types are the same - **IO ()**.

*2) Right identity:* **m >>= return ≡ m**

```
var x = Rx.Observable.of(1);

x.flatMap(x => Observable.of(x)) :: Observable
x                                :: ScalarObservable
```

HASKELL:

```
Just 2 >>= return  :: Num b => Maybe b
Just 2             :: Num a => Maybe a
```

The same situation as with the left identity. Observable !== ScalarObservable. Whereas in Haskell, the type stays the same, it's a Maybe with a Num inside it.

*3) Associativity*

**(m >>= f) >>= g      ≡      m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)**

```
var x = Rx.Observable.of(10)

var func1 = (x) => Rx.Observable.of(x + 1)
var func2 = (x) => Rx.Observable.of(x + 2)


x.flatMap(func1).flatMap(func2)         :: Observable
x.flatMap(e => func1(e).flatMap(func2)) :: Observable
```

HASKELL:

```
add2 x = Just(x + 2)
add1 x = Just(x + 1)

Just 2 >>= add1 >>= add2             :: Num b => Maybe b
Just 2 >>= (\x -> add1(x) >>= add2)  :: Num b => Maybe b
```

This is the only law that seems to hold for Observable.
But I don't know, maybe this should not be reasoned in the way I did. What do you think?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ScalarObservable` is just an optimisation specialisation for `Observable<Number>`. Notice that the law doesn't state the two sides need to return the exact same value, but just that they need to behave equally.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I was hoping on such an answer. In the end, in https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws, we can read that _"Here, p ≡ q simply means that you can replace p with q and vice-versa, and the behaviour of your program will not change: p and q are equivalent."_. Would that mean that if we do `x.flatMap(x => Observable.of(x)).subscribe(a => console.log(a))` and `x.subscribe(a => console.log(a))` and we end up with the same side effect, then it's enough proof for the *Left identity* to hold for Observable?

Comment: That's the right identity, but in general yes

Answer (score 21):

**tldr;** Yes.

---

JavaScript is a dynamic language with duck typing so in runtime, instance of an `Observable` class is *equivalent* to an instance of `ScalarObservable`. RxJS itself is written in TypeScript and these irregularities do not surface up in types and they are - exactly as @Bergi wrote in a comment - an optimisation. On the other hand, you are completely right: in a nominal type system type mismatch could be a real problem and even a compile time error.

---

Now, answering the question itself - please take a look at a [Purescript library](https://github.com/jasonzoladz/purescript-rxjs/blob/master/src/RxJS/Observable.purs#L118-L157) with bindings to RxJS:

```
foreign import data Observable :: Type -> Type

instance monoidObservable :: Monoid (Observable a) where
  mempty = _empty

instance functorObservable :: Functor Observable where
  map = _map

instance applyObservable :: Apply Observable where
  apply = combineLatest id

instance applicativeObservable :: Applicative Observable where
  pure = just

instance bindObservable :: Bind Observable where
  bind = mergeMap

instance monadObservable :: Monad Observable

-- | NOTE: The semigroup instance uses `merge` NOT `concat`.
instance semigroupObservable :: Semigroup (Observable a) where
  append = merge

instance altObservable :: Alt Observable where
  alt = merge

instance plusObservable :: Plus Observable where
  empty = _empty

instance alternativeObservable :: Alternative Observable

instance monadZeroObservable :: MonadZero Observable

instance monadPlusObservable :: MonadPlus Observable

instance monadErrorObservable :: MonadError Error Observable where
  catchError = catch

instance monadThrowObservable :: MonadThrow Error Observable where
  throwError = throw
```

Assuming Purescript types are correct: apart from being a regular `Monad`, `Observable` conforms to `MonadPlus` and `MonadError` classes. `MonadPlus` allows to combine computations, while `MonadError` allows to interrupt or skip some part of computations (in case of `Observable` we can easily retry computations as well).
`Observable` is not only a monad, but a very powerful one - *maybe* even the most powerful monad used in the main**stream$**.

I do not have any formal proofs, but can shortly describe how to use Observable to model or replace monads describe in https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads.

**Maybe** *Computations which may not return a result*

Non-result can be represented as regular JS `undefined` or an `EMPTY` stream.

**Error** *Computations which can fail or throw exceptions*

You can throw regular JS errors or return more idiomatic `throwError` from monadic bind. An error can be catch'ed and then handled or use to retry computations. Throwing an error immediately stops ongoing computations.

**List** *Non-deterministic computations which can return multiple possible results*

List is kind of a younger brother of Observable, lacking entirely the time dimension. Anything that can be expressed via operations on a list can be exactly mapped to operations on an observable. You can easily lift a list via `Observable.from` and downgrade to observable with `.toList()`. Being native, list performance is going to be much better than observable's. But remember that list is eager and observable lazy, so in some cases observable may outperform list.

**IO** *Computations which perform I/O*

Any IO operations (network, disk etc) can be easily wrapped / lifted to the observable world.

**State** *Computations which maintain state*

BehaviorSubject

**Reader** *Computations which read from a shared environment*

From a consumer perspective it does not matter at all where an instance of *Observable* comes from. For example: if you declared your config as an observable you can easily change the exact environment from where the value(s) are provided.

**Writer** *Computations which write data in addition to computing values*

The simplest option is to return two streams one with values and the other with logs / auxiliary data.

**Cont** *Computations which can be interrupted and restarted*

To interrupt computations you can throw an error, use an operator e.g. `.switchMap`, `.takeUntil`, explicitly unsubscribe or `.mergeMap` to `EMPTY`. Having access to some form of a cache restarting *deterministic* computations from arbitrary step is pretty trivial: just split your computations to smaller observables and cache their results once computed; when restarted run computations only if cache empty - otherwise use cached value.

---

If you decide to use observables to represent structure of your computations - you not only can model / replace the most common monads used in practice, but your computations are automatically reactive in flavour. Moreover if you stick to only observable your computations are going to be homogenous, which means there is very little or no need for monad transformers and accidental complexity introduced by them.
My working hypothesis is that observable type offers some local (or even global) maximum for expressing structure of asynchronous computations. For example: Observable offers not one, not two, but **three!** monadic binds with different semantic: `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `exhaustMap` (if you wonder: `concatMap` is actually a special case of `mergeMap`). This very fact on its own is kind of indication that observable is a very interesting mathematical structure.

---

**A bonus**

Observable is said to be a stream and streams (in general) are [commonads] (https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/01/02/comonads/). Does it mean that observable is not only a monad but a comonad as well?

[Erik Meijer twit's](https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/244544069110476800):

> @rix0rrr For a while Rx had a ManySelect operator. Rx is both a monad and a comonad. 144 characters is too short to explain that. Sorry ;-)

Comment: There's actually a 5th mode, shown here http://www.deanius.com/ConcurModes2.png and playfully discussed here: https://dev.to/deanius/declarative-concurrency-with-rx-helper-and-rxjs-30ai

Comment: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/10_LeavingTheMonad.html

Comment: It seems that Observable is quite powerful abstraction but I wonder if there's a place for AsyncIterator for pull-based data flow and can an app successfully use both push and pull abstractions at the same time.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai sorry for a late reply. You can easily integrate a pull-based interface into a push-based architecture: you internally pull with some frequency and expose the results as a stream. From the perspective of the consumer of the stream it does not matter. The other way around it is more challenging from my experience: a streaming source has a tendency to *contaminate* its surroundings; the data **really** want to flow and the abstraction leaks.

Comment: Going from push to pull seems to mean you need either: A. a database, B: backpressure, C: buffer overflow mechanisms.